# Targeting Net Framework library from Azure Functions V2

Tags: c#, azure-functions

So I've got a Net 4.72 class library that is going to handle the processing and logic of what is happening on my backend that can't be upgraded to a Net Standard project because of its dependencies.

I understand that it might be possible to set my Azure Functions V2 project to multi target for Core and Framework (Maybe that isn't possible?) but am not sure how to do it or if that would even solve my problem.

I tried something like this but have been getting a slew of errors,

**Functions V2 csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net472;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v2</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  ...
</Project>
```

Basically I just need my Functions V2 project to be able to hand its data off to the Framework class library. Is this possible?

Comment: Might want to read [this](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/790).  As far as I know, Functions V2 will _only_ support .NET Standard/.NET Core libraries

Comment: Thanks, its unfortunately what I was afraid of :(

Comment: you can just have different function apps targeting different frameworks